# jquery draggable offsetting on first drop

Tags: jquery-ui

Using JQuery UI draggable/droppable I am running into an issue where the draggable drop area is offset (normally to the left but inconsistent distance). The image can be directly over the drop area and fail and on next attempt, in exact same location, pass.

So, dragged item looks in correct spot over mouse but is incorrect when dropped... but only first attempt.

```
function dragAndDrop(draggedItem,dropZone,size)
{
    var bool = 0;
    var draggedItem = $(draggedItem);
    var dragFromLeft = draggedItem.offset().left;
    var dragFromTop = draggedItem.offset().top;
    var dropZone = $(dropZone);
    //var size = size;


    draggedItem.draggable //Make item draggable
    ({
        opacity:1, 
        revert:function()//'invalid'
        {
            $(".strobeRed").fadeTo(100, .50).fadeTo(100, 0);
            $(this).offset({top: dragFromTop, left: dragFromLeft})
        },
        drag:function(event, ui)
        {
            $(this).height(size);
            $(this).width(size);
        },
        cursorAt:
        {
            left:(size/2),
            top:(size/2)
        }
    }); 

    dropZone.droppable //Make item droppable
    ({
        accept:draggedItem,
        drop: function(event, ui)
        {
            $( ui.draggable ).fadeOut(),
            $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ).css("background-color", "green"), //$(this) = $(event.target)
            $( this ).draggable( "option", "disabled", true )
        }
    });
}
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/errar.jpg)

*** EDIT 1** 
 **Adding function call from edge animate ***
draggable and droppable objects are just divs with class names.

```
yepnope({nope:['jquery-ui.js','cookbook.js'],complete:init});
function init(){
dragAndDrop(".item1",'.dz1',50);
dragAndDrop(".item2",'.dz2',50);
dragAndDrop(".item3",'.dz3',50);
dragAndDrop(".item4",'.dz4',50);
dragAndDrop(".item5",'.dz5',50);
dragAndDrop(".item6",'.dz6',50);
dragAndDrop(".item7",'.dz7',50);
dragAndDrop(".item8",'.dz8',50);
dragAndDrop(".item9",'.dz9',50);
}
```

*** EDIT 2** 
 **fixed issue, introduced another ***
by having the scale prior to adding the draggable, it now drops correctly. The new issue is the first item I touch of each type scales and relocates to pointer but the drops. It doesn't fail it just stops being dragged.

```
    function dragAndDrop(draggedItem,dropZone,scaleHeight,scaleWidth)
    {
    var bool = 0;
    var draggedItem = $(draggedItem);
    var dragFromLeft = draggedItem.offset().left;
    var dragFromTop = draggedItem.offset().top;
    var dropZone = $(dropZone);
    var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

    draggedItem.mousedown(function(event){
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX - (scaleWidth/2);
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY - (scaleHeight/2);
    $(this).height(scaleHeight);
    $(this).width(scaleWidth);
    $(this).offset({top: currentMousePos.y, left: currentMousePos.x});

    draggedItem.draggable //Make item draggable
    ({
        opacity:1, 
        revert:function()//'invalid'
        {
            $(".strobeRed").fadeTo(100, .50).fadeTo(100, 0);
            $(this).offset({top: dragFromTop, left: dragFromLeft})
        }
    })
});

dropZone.droppable //Make item droppable
({
    accept:draggedItem,
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        //$( ui.draggable ).fadeOut(),
        $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ).css("background-color", "green"), //$(this) = $(event.target)
        $( this ).draggable( "option", "disabled", true )
    },
    tolerance: "touch"
});
```

}

Comment: can u share the HTML/fiddle as well?

Comment: it's being made in edge animate. **Tried to add code here but didn't work. Will add in original

Comment: @ryan what is the initial size of `draggable` `divs`?

Comment: width 109, height 184. That question had me thinking so I had the guy who is building the edge file make the PNG the same size as the div. That didn't help. It seems to me that the drop is being calculated off the div size pre-scaled and since the scale is permanent, the second time the math is accurate. I am believing that I need to find a way of calculating the scaled div size before the droppable happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** I FOUND IT **
Ok, so my first attempt was calculating the draggable as its original size. The second attempt was not dragging the first item of each type during first attempt. I believe it was stuck in mousedown event and not running the draggable. every time after that draggable was already applied so it worked.

The fix was to assign draggable to everything in the beginning but pull the scaling into a second function. It now scales the item, centers it on mouse, drags and drops.

```
function dragAndDrop(draggedItem,dropZone,scaleHeight,scaleWidth)
{
var bool = 0;
var draggedItem = $(draggedItem);
var dragFromLeft = draggedItem.offset().left;
var dragFromTop = draggedItem.offset().top;
var dropZone = $(dropZone);
var currentMousePos = { x: 0, y: 0};

draggedItem.draggable //Make item draggable
({
    opacity:1, 
    revert:function()//'invalid'
    {
        $(".strobeRed").fadeTo(100, .50).fadeTo(100, 0);
        $(this).offset({top: dragFromTop, left: dragFromLeft})
    }
})

draggedItem.mousedown(function(event){
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX - (scaleWidth/2);  
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY - (scaleHeight/2);
    $(this).height(scaleHeight);
    $(this).width(scaleWidth);
    $(this).offset({top: currentMousePos.y, left: currentMousePos.x});
});

dropZone.droppable //Make item droppable
({
    accept:draggedItem,
    drop: function(event, ui)
    {
        //$( ui.draggable ).fadeOut(),
        $( this ).droppable( "option", "disabled", true ).css("background-color", "green"), //$(this) = $(event.target)
        $( this ).draggable( "option", "disabled", true )
    },
    tolerance: "touch"
});
}
```